# How to install SSL and change the admin URL

Tags: orocommerce

How to install Let's encrypt SSL certificate with automated renewal and also change the admin URL for orocommerce?

Comment: can someone please assist on this. thank you #orocommerce

Comment: Hi, i need to add whatsapp javascript to footer, is there a simple way to do that? thanks @orocommerce

Answer (score 1):

There are two unrelated questions.

> How to install Let's encrypt SSL certificate with automated renewal

There is no difference from other applications in this step, so you can follow the general installation guide provided by Let's encrypt for your operation system.

> change the admin URL for orocommerce?

You can do it from the management console by modifying the [Application URL](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/configuration/system/general-setup/application/#admin-configuration-application) and [Website URL and Secure URLs](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/websites/web-configuration/general-sys-config/websites/website-routing/#sys-websites-sysconfig-websites-routing) or the command line:

```
php bin/console oro:config:update --env=prod oro_ui.application_url <new application-url>
php bin/console console oro:config:update --env=prod oro_website.url <new application-url>
php bin/console console oro:config:update --env=prod oro_website.secure_url <new application-url>
```

where the `<new application-url>` must be replaced with your application URL, like https://example.com.

Comment: Thank you Andrey. what I meant is I want to change the word "/admin" to something else e.g. " https://example.com/controlpanel" as I can't find this in the documentation or the management console

Comment: You can change it by setting the web_backend_prefix parameter in the config/parameters.yml file

Comment: Hi Andrey, I just changed this but it's not working, is there another step after modifying the config/parameters.yml? Thank you #orocommerce